# automating a chain of shell commands with os.popen Python and 'sudo' is not recognized

Tags: operating-system

My shell commands worked fine when I manually and sequentially executed them, however, when I tried to automate them, I got an error message:

```
'sudo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

My code is shown below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import os
import subprocess
import serial
import serial.threaded

def get_output_boot():

 response1 = os.popen('ssh username@10.40.20.46 cd /tests && sudo 
 ./reboot_board.py emmc && python -m serial.tools.list_ports -v')
 output = response1.read()
 print(output)  
  #expected output
 '''
/dev/ttyAMA0
desc: ttyAMA0
hwid: 3f201000.serial
/dev/ttyUSB0
desc: Quad RS232-HS
hwid: USB VID:PID=0403:6011 LOCATION=1-1.2:1.0
/dev/ttyUSB1
desc: Quad RS232-HS
hwid: USB VID:PID=0403:6011 LOCATION=1-1.2:1.1
/dev/ttyUSB2
desc: Quad RS232-HS
hwid: USB VID:PID=0403:6011 LOCATION=1-1.2:1.2
/dev/ttyUSB3
desc: Quad RS232-HS
hwid: USB VID:PID=0403:6011 LOCATION=1-1.2:1.3
5 ports found
'''

if __name__ == '__main__':

 get_output_boot()
```

Can someone please help me resolve this problem.  I am ultimately trying to parse some serial output from USB but can't get past the 'sudo' error message.

Answer (score 0):

I did some research and got the problem resolved using subprocess.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#
# 
#
import sys
import os
import subprocess
import serial

command1 = ['ssh','user@10.40.20.46']
command2 = ['cd','/workspace/mset-utils/tests']
command3 = ['sudo','./reboot_board.py']
command4 = ['python', '-m','serial.tools.list_ports', '-v'] 
cmd_and = ['&&']
#commands = command1 + command2 + command3 + cmd_and + 
 command4
 ''' getting same output as running at command line 
 $ sudo ./reboot_board.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./reboot_board.py", line 44, in <module>
mode = argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
----> have to reset the connection
'''
commands = command1 + command2 + cmd_and + command4
''' getting expected response
$ python Test_code_Popen_serial_connection_3_14_20.py
user@10.40.20.46's password:
5 ports found
/dev/ttyAMA0
desc: ttyAMA0
hwid: 3f201000.serial
/dev/ttyUSB0
desc: Quad RS232-HS
hwid: USB VID:PID=0403:6011 LOCATION=1-1.2:1.0
/dev/ttyUSB1
desc: Quad RS232-HS
hwid: USB VID:PID=0403:6011 LOCATION=1-1.2:1.1
/dev/ttyUSB2
desc: Quad RS232-HS
hwid: USB VID:PID=0403:6011 LOCATION=1-1.2:1.2
/dev/ttyUSB3
desc: Quad RS232-HS
hwid: USB VID:PID=0403:6011 LOCATION=1-1.2:1.3
'''

process = subprocess.Popen(commands, 
                       stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                       universal_newlines=True)

while True:
output = process.stdout.readline()
print(output.strip())
# Do something else
return_code = process.poll()
if return_code is not None:
    print('RETURN CODE', return_code)
    # Process has finished, read rest of the output 
    for output in process.stdout.readlines():
        print(output.strip())
    break
```